# PHP: strtotime() doesn't add the correct amount of days

Tags: php, string, date, datetime

I have the command `date('d.m.y', strtotime('22.02.21 +1 days'))`. The expected output would be 23.02.21, however I am getting 26.02.21. It adds four days, not one. When trying to add two days, it adds five.

Using a different date-format (i.e. `date('d.m.y', strtotime('02/22/21 +1 days'))`) works, however I'd like to use this date format, if possible.

Is there a way to make `strtotime()` work with this format?

Comment: See [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: `date('d.m.y', strtotime('2021-02-22 +1 day'));` would be closer

Comment: Even *I* can't tell what date "22.02.21" is supposed to be exactly, so I can sympathise with `strtotime`'s confusion…

Comment: @deceze♦ it's the normal date format in Germany. 22nd of February 2021

Comment: Is PHP German…?

Comment: FWIW, `22.02.21` also wouldn't be atypical in Japan and could be Feb. 21st 2022 or possibly Feb. 21st 2010 (Heisei 22)…

Comment: You're feeding `strtotime()` with [22:02:21 in your current time zone](https://3v4l.org/sshgm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php.

strtotime expects to be given a string containing an **English date format** and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp.

Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) **or a dot(.) visibly**, then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-) **or a dot(.) visibly**, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

```
date("d.m.y", strtotime("2021-02-22 +1 day"))
```

To avoid confusion it is better to use a date with the year on 4 digits

```
date('d.m.y', strtotime('22.02.2021 +1 days'))
```

And finally, to avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a two digit year you need to disambiguate the century anyway. Using a four digit year will work.

In this example any year starting 70 is assumed to be in the 20th century while all other years are in the 21st century.

```
$inputDate = '22.02.21';
$year = substr($inputDate, 6);
if ( $year > 69 ) {
    $year = '19' . $year;
} else {
    $year = '20' . $year;
}
$date = substr($inputDate, 0, 6) . $year;

echo date("d.m.y", strtotime($date . ' +1 day'));
```

Sandbox example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14a79178f8909f3078666ae630163fa7c943cff1